# FormatException was unhandled occurs

Tags: c#

I have declared character array in my C# console application.

My code:

```
char[] address = new char[30];
char[] blood_Grp = new char[10];

public void getdata()
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter your address");

    // here I am getting FormatException was unhandled exception 
    address[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Please help me to cure my coding..

Comment: Please edit your post and use code tags to format your code and also include the stacktrace for where you get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are reading a complete line (an array of `chars`). If the length of input is greater than 1, `FormatException` will be thrown.

You should use [`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
address[i] = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

It has a property [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx), so you don't need to convert it to `char` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.readline%28VS.80%29.aspx) will return string

then you can use [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ezftk57x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get chars

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string address = Console.ReadLine();
```

or...

```
char[] address = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
```